# Specific upload folder for PDFs in custom Post type in WP multisite

Tags: multisite, customization, uploads

I need to filter uploads to a specific folder for a custom-post type called "document" only for PDFs.

So far, I have:

```
function custom_upload_directory( $args ) {
$base_directory = '/home/xxx/my_uploadfolder';
$base_url = 'http://xxxx/wp-content/uploads/my_uploadfolder';

$id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
$parent = get_post( $id )->post_parent;
// Check the post-type of the current post

if( "document" == get_post_type( $id ) || "document" == get_post_type( $parent ) ) {
    $args['path'] = $base_directory;
    $args['url']  = $base_url;
    $args['basedir'] = $base_directory;
    $args['baseurl'] = $base_url;

}

return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'custom_upload_directory' );
```

It works, but with some problems: : any kind of file is redirected in my_uploadfolder. Also, I can't delete these files from WP admin once there. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2):

you might consider using

```
if(get_post_mime_type($id) == 'application/pdf'){
   ...
}
```

to check for pdf files.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type

You might also take a look at the code behind the **wp_delete_attachment()** function and you can hook into it with the  **delete attachment** action. To remove the files you can use **unlink()**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're having trouble here is that you're applying a universal filter to `upload_dir`.  Rather than doing this, use a conditional filter for `upload_dir` after first checking `['mime-type']` for `application/pdf`.  You need to intercept the upload process at the `wp_handle_upload` action hook and alter the upload folder there.  What you have posted is heading in the right direction, but you need to be working with the incoming `$_POST` data and applying the filter there by searching for uploading files `['mime-type']` which WordPress stores during the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was 10 years ago but just incase someone is looking for code that works this will make a pdf folder in your uploads and put all pdf there so yourl will be siteurl/wp-content/uploads/pdf/filename.pdf

```
function custom_upload_directory( $args ) {
    // Check if the uploaded file is a PDF
    if ( ! empty( $_FILES['async-upload']['type'] ) && $_FILES['async-upload']['type'] === 'application/pdf' ) {
        // Define the custom folder path
        $custom_folder = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/pdf/';
        $custom_url = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads/pdf/';
        
        // Add the file name to the custom folder path
        $file_name = $_FILES['async-upload']['name'];
        $custom_folder = $custom_folder . $file_name;
        $custom_url = $custom_url . $file_name;
        
        $args['path'] = dirname($custom_folder);
        $args['url'] = dirname($custom_url);
        $args['basedir'] = dirname($custom_folder);
        $args['baseurl'] = dirname($custom_url);
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'custom_upload_directory' );
```