# How to add subfolders in media library for better organisation?

Tags: media-library

Right now I cannot create any subfolder e.g. reviews, news, interviews etc. I have a lot of images in my media library and it's messy.

How can I create some folders and reorganize the images there?

Comment: Basically, how do you create attachment taxonomies and display them in the media uploader? The first part is easy, just pass in 'attachment' as the post type, but the last part is interesting, I'd like to know myself. Modify your question and perhaps you'll gather more interest

Comment: Yes, agreed with @TomJNowell, folders are not possible, AFAIK. There's an Answer here somewhere showing how to add custom taxonomies to Attachments, what's needed is adding the same dropdown filters as in Posts.

Comment: Hmm, I am wondering how can bigger websites that are using WP deal with that e.g. Techcrunch, Mashable? I have maybe 100 articles and every article has from 1-5 images and it's a big mess now. What can I do with that? I would like to stay with WP, becasue of other superior features when comapred with Joomla or Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

I too use have been using the [Custom Upload Dir plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) that @sr83 mentioned to organise images and other upload files. It's a useful solution, although not as flexible as I would like.

It does provide a really great range of placeholders to build the folder path dynamically - including %file_ext%, %post_id%, %author%, %postname%, %post_type%, %year%, 
%monthnum%, %current_user%, %category%, etc -, however that structure remains set and cannot be modified on-the-fly during upload.

I find this helpful as a general day-to-day setting for authors contributing posts, but I find that I need to change the setup when I want to upload core static page images etc, then change it back again.

The following post provides some pointers for creating your own upload handler that - along with looking at how [Custom Upload Dir plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) works - might give you the necessary pieces to build something more flexible yourself:

[Specific upload folder for PDFs in custom Post type in WP multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83933/)